# trouble with switch case statement

Tags: java, android

what I am trying to do is to get 2 playlists from website. But when i get lists it fills first list with good items. and in the second it puts first and adds second.... and i dont ged it why. 
So I get it with:

```
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
parseMusic(rd,choice);
conn.disconnect();
```

and hier i try to put in 2 playlist (not simultaneously). So I call it 2 times. Query's on website returns wright lists. 
It goes with PLchoice and in first and in second case.. thaths why i get second list wright and first is second+first one... why?

```
 private void parseMusic(BufferedReader reader,int PLchoice) throws IOException {
    String line=null;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] values = line.split(",");

        switch (PLchoice){
        case 1: {
            if(musicList != null) {
                if(values[0].equals("null")) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", "no music found!");
                } else {
                    int id = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
                    String filename = values[1];

                    musicList.add(new Mp3(id, filename));
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ERROR", "MusicList = null");
            }
        }
        case 3:{
            if(secondList != null) {
                if(values[0].equals("null")) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", "no music found!");
                } else {
                    int id = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
                    String filename = values[1];

                secondList.add(new Mp3(id, filename));
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ERROR", "MusicList = null");
                }   
            }
        }           
    }
    reader.close(); 
          Log.e("playList","MP3 file muslist= "+musicList);
    Log.e("playList added","MP3 file secondList= "+secondList);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `break` out of each case statement (the brackets are also unnecessary).

[Java Switch Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: shoet... i see.. stuppid of me!

Answer (score 0):

This is what is called a switch-fallthrough. You need to have a `break;` line after the end of the body of each case as otherwise all the code following the matched case (including other cases) will get executed.